# .profile file for setting up ENV variable for stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, stripe-payments

I'd like to know where is .profile file lies in ubuntu? I in fact need to setup in there my publishable & secret key which i get from stripe. 
My instructor showed me an example on C9 where he just clicked on menu & after checked on hidden files all hidden files were appeard, whereas I'm working on local environment (Atom) I'm unable to see .profile.

Comment: On Ubuntu your profile is at `~/.profile`. But use [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/) instead.

Comment: great tks!.....